# How to get li chechbox checked status in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-lists, checked

How to get `li checkbox` checked status in jquery.

I want like this one, but its throw me undefined.

```
$('#ul'+$Id+' li:nth-child('+_index+') span input:checkbox').attr("checked")
```

can anyone help from out of this one.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) on your jQuery object.

```
$('#ul'+$Id+' li:nth-child('+_index+') span input:checkbox').is(':checked');
```

Comment: Its return only false not true

Answer (score 0):

Why variable $id in javascript??
   Is _index variable?

You can check a check-box like

```
$(selector).prop('checked', true);
$(selector).prop('checked', false);
$(selector).attr('checked','checked');
$(selector).removeAttr('checked');
alert($(selector).is(':checked'));
```

Comment: $Id holds the id of the checked below the ul

Comment: But in javascript $id is invalid variable